# Having trouble uploading symbol file - FCR_PROD_VERS: not set

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I am having trouble uploading symbol files for Firebase Crash Reporting.

Using the command line, when I navigate to my Xcode project folder and run the command as instructed:

```
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX
```

I get the following error:

> FCR_PROD_VERS: not set (check GoogleService-Info.plist and Info.plist
>   settings)

How and where do I set this? Why is this not set automatically?

Answer (score 3):

**batch-upload** tries to get as much information from the workspace that it can, but some things may not be easily discoverable. If it cannot find these values, you can help it by supplying them yourself.

- SERVICE_PLIST - path to *GoogleService-Info.plist* (**-p** command-line option)
- INFO_PLIST - path to *Info.plist* (**-i** command-line option)
- FCR_BUNDLE_ID - `CFBundleIdentifier` from *Info.plist*
- FCR_DUMP_SYMS - path to **dump_syms** executable
- FCR_PROD_VERS - `CFBundleShortVersionString` (marketing version) from *Info.plist*
- FIREBASE_API_KEY - API key (`API_KEY`) from *GoogleService-Info.plist*
- FIREBASE_APP_ID - App ID (`GOOGLE_APP_ID`) from *GoogleService-Info.plist*
- SWIFT_DEMANGLE - path to **swift-demangle** executable (use "/bin/cat" if not using Swift to avoid some innocuous warnings)

So if the marketing version is "7.2.3", you can avoid the above error by

```
$ env FCR_PROD_VERS="7.2.3" Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload \
    72C2FABA-2092-4817-A1C7-3E3281AA84DA
```

Or even better, if you can find the executable corresponding to the UUID:

```
$ dwarfdump --uuid build/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp
UUID: 72C2FABA-2092-4817-A1C7-3E3281AA84DA (arm64) ...
UUID: 1800251C-9147-3642-92DA-818B97144148 (armv7) ...

$ env FCR_PROD_VERS="7.2.3" Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload \
    build/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp
```

Please understand that **batch-upload** is not the normal way to upload symbols for post-crash analysis: that job should be done by **upload-sym** within an Xcode build itself (where it has access to more information than **batch-upload**).

(These tools are becoming complicated enough to demand their own man pages.)

Comment: This got me closer to being able to upload but now I get a dialog box asking:    Where is the service account file?  What is that and where would it be located?

Comment: in the console before the dialog it says this also: Error reading object file: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-06-28/myappname 6-28-16, 9.17 AM.xcarchive:

Comment: Sorry, was on vacation. You should have downloaded a service account JSON file as part of your setup. Please make sure you followed all the steps in https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#upload_symbol_files to prepare your app for uploading symbols. Again, remember that batch-upload is for unusual cases, e.g., third-party precompiled libraries or multipart builds outside of Xcode: the warning indicates that not all of the instructions were followed correctly, and the system is trying to recover for you what it can.